# How to incorporate a class into this code for Mastermind?

Tags: python, class

I am stuck on how to implement a class into this code. I am pretty new to coding and this is my first project. The player is supposed to try to guess a computer-generated sequence of colors, and I am having trouble with implementing a class.

I am also somewhat puzzled about my try and except statement. I am trying to keep the code going even if the player input is wrong, but not count that as a guess and I can't figure that out.

The basic program works, but I am trying to make it more streamlined and less confusing, possibly making big chunks of it a function or class.

```
'''
-------- MASTERMIND --------
'''

from random import choice, sample #importing these for list generation and list randomization

game_active = True
color_choices = ["r","g","b","y","o","p"]   #choices for the player and computer
player_color_guess = ["","","",""]  #player inputed colors
computer_color_guess = [choice(color_choices),choice(color_choices),choice(color_choices),choice(color_choices)]    #generates random 4 choices for the computer
guesses = 0 #keeps track of number of guesses

def you_win():  #function for winning the game
    return("You beat the codemaker in " + str(guesses) + " guesses! Great job!")
    return("Press any key to exit")

def clean_list(ugly_list):  #function that cleans the brackets and other symbols from a list
    return(str(ugly_list).replace(',','').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'',''))



print("Welcome to Mastermind!\n\n----------------------\n\nI will make a code of four colors: \nRed(r)\nGreen(g)\nBlue(b)\nYellow(y)\nOrange(o)\nPurple(p)\nGuess the combination of colors. If you get the correct color and the correct place you will get a '+', if you guess \nthe correct color and the wrong place you will get a '~', otherwise you will get a '-'. \nThe position of the symbols do not correlate to the positions of the colors.")

while game_active:  
    #making main loop for the game
    player_guess_symbols = []
    #this is to store the first output of symbols, not mixed
    num_correct = 0    #to store number of correct guesses

    '''try:'''
    player_color_guess = str(input("\nInput four colors, separated by a comma.\n>>>  ").split(','))     #actual player input
    guesses += 1    #every time the player does this it adds one to guess variable

    '''except ValueError:
        print("{} is not a valid input.".format(player_color_guess))'''

    for clr in range(0,4):  #looping through first four numbers: 0,1,2,3
        if computer_color_guess[clr] == player_color_guess[clr]: #takes the index clr and compares it to the player guess
            player_guess_symbols.append("+")
            num_correct += 1

        elif computer_color_guess[clr] in player_color_guess:   #checks if computer guess is in player guess
            player_guess_symbols.append("~")

        else:
            player_guess_symbols.append("-")

    if guesses > 10:    #this is to check the number of guesses, and see if the player wins
        print("You failed to guess the code in 8 guesses or under! The correct code was " + clean_list(computer_color_guess) + ". Press any key to exit")
        break   #not sure if this is the right place for a break statement

    player_guess_symbols_mixed = sample(player_guess_symbols, len(player_guess_symbols))    
    #this mixes the symbol output each time so the placement of the symbols is not a pattern

    if num_correct > 3: #checks of player wins
        print(you_win())

    print(clean_list(player_guess_symbols_mixed))
```

Comment: It's a case of looking at which data belongs where and which functions you can provide that works on that data and keeps it consistent and encapsulated. This is a very broadly scoped question, (which are not encouraged on SO as it leads to a slew of opinionated and long winded answers), the best resolution from a learning point of view is to read a decent book on OO design, no answer here will ever match that for thoroughness and breadth. Read about things like [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) and see if that gives you any food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually pretty well formatted for your first project, so kudos for that! You've done a great job naming your variables, having some meaningful comments, and using whitespace correctly (although Python forces you to do that last thing, it's still pretty key). Keep up the good work!

Usually this sort of thing isn't exactly the right fit for Stack Overflow, but I'll try to give you a few tips.

With regards to your try and except, you could wrap it in another loop, or perhaps use a `continue` statement:

```
try:
    player_color_guess = str(input("\nInput four colors, separated by a comma.\n>>>  ").split(','))     #actual player input
    guesses += 1    #every time the player does this it adds one to guess variable
except ValueError:
    print("{} is not a valid input.".format(player_color_guess))
    continue  # go back to while
```

Sometimes using `continue` can lead to spaghetti, but in this case I think avoiding extra indentation is simpler. It works similar to the `break` statement, only instead of breaking out of the loop altogether, it just goes back to the `while` or `for` or what-have-you.

---

Putting it into a class is a bit less straightforward. To be honest I'm not sure you need it all that much as the code is fairly readable as is! But a place I might start, is looking at encapsulating the current game state:

```
class GuessState:  # could easily call this MastermindState or what-have-you
    guesses = 0
    computer_guess = []
    player_guess = []  # could be a good place to story a history of player guesses
```

This gives you a really good place to make a function for setting up `computer_guess`, say in an `__init__` function:

```
    def __init__(self):
         self.computer_guess = [ ... etc ... ]
```

And you can also put some of the game logic there to help make things more readable:

```
    def check_player_guess(self, guess):
         # check self.computer_guess against guess
         # maybe increment self.guesses here too
         # maybe return True if the guess was correct?

    def scramble_player_guess(self):
         return sample(self.player_guess, len(player_guess))
```

Now the setup and the game loop can be much simpler:

```
state = GuessState()
while(game_active):

     player_guess = str(input... etc ...)  # might also be a good thing to put in a function

     if state.check_player_guess(player_guess):
          print "win in {}".format(state.guesses)
          break

     if state.out_of_guesses():
          print "lose"
          break  # is actually pretty reasonable

     print state.scramble_player_guess()
```

You'd need to implement `check_player_guess` and `out_of_guesses` of course :) This helps separate interpreting user input from the game logic, as well as from what you print out. It's not *all* the way there -- e.g. it'd take a bit more work to make it easy to drop in a graphical interface vs a text-based one -- but it's a little closer.

You could argue about the right way to do this quite a bit also, and you can look at the edit history to see some of the changes I went through in the process of writing this post even -- sometimes you don't see things until after you've stepped away a little. Does that help?

Comment: Btw: in the future you might look at the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193139/comparing-data-in-sql-using-foreign-keys) Stack Exchange :) it's a great place to ask for tips and tricks.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. I guess I just had trouble putting it into words. I had a lot of trouble with the `try` and `except` statement, and trying to make that work for incorrect guesses. Thanks a lot! Sorry about it not being a very pointed question.

Comment: Np, welcome to Stack Overflow! It can be a prickly place sometimes but it is a great source for answering questions. As long as you put thought into your questions (which you have), I'm sure you'll do fine.